# How to make this code dynamic and work with a CMS (not static content)?

Tags: jquery

Im making a navigation similar to www.yesstudio.co.uk. When you scroll down the page a fixed position image changes to show one of the images.

Here is my example which is working fine. Ive made the images that will be hidden semi transparent so you can see whats going on.
http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/demo/12.html

The issue is that the javascript that swaps out the image is manually repeated the required 8 times. Ive also hard coded in the image's src to be changed. Im going to use this code with a CMS so I need a smarter solution that gets the image's src from the page and also works with more than 8 images.

```
$(window).bind("load scroll", function() {  

            // get the height of the page
            var bodyHeight = $('body').height();        

            //get the current scroll position
            var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();

            //get the height of the viewport 
            var viewportHeight = $(window).height();    

            //get the number of images in the list
            var numberImages = $("#image-list img").size(); 

            //the amount needed to scroll for each image is the page height minus the viewport height, 
            var scrollInterval = ( (bodyHeight - viewportHeight) / (numberImages) ); 


            //for each scroll intervall assign the correct image. 
            if (scrollPos < scrollInterval) {
                $('#img-main').attr('src', 'images/1.jpg');
            }
            if (scrollPos > scrollInterval && scrollPos < (scrollInterval*2) )  {   
                $('#img-main').attr('src', 'images/2.jpg');
            }
            if (scrollPos > (scrollInterval*2) && scrollPos < (scrollInterval*3) )  {
                $('#img-main').attr('src', 'images/3.jpg');
            }
            if (scrollPos > (scrollInterval*3) && scrollPos < (scrollInterval*4) )  {
                $('#img-main').attr('src', 'images/4.jpg');
            }
            if (scrollPos > (scrollInterval*4) && scrollPos < (scrollInterval*5) )  {
                $('#img-main').attr('src', 'images/5.jpg');
            }
            if (scrollPos > (scrollInterval*5) && scrollPos < (scrollInterval*6) )  {
                $('#img-main').attr('src', 'images/6.jpg');
            }
            if (scrollPos > (scrollInterval*6) && scrollPos < (scrollInterval*7) )  {
                $('#img-main').attr('src', 'images/7.jpg');
            }
            if (scrollPos > (scrollInterval*7) && scrollPos < (scrollInterval*8) )  {
                $('#img-main').attr('src', 'images/8.jpg');
            }               

        });
```

UPDATE - could someone tell me the things I should be googeling to figure this out? I dont know where to start at the moment. Thanks

UPDATE - the file names wont always be the neat 1.jpg. 2.jpg etc. They can be anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#img-main').attr('src', 'images/' + (scrollPos / scrollInterval).toString() + '.jpg');
```

Comment: It would not be modulo... it should be division.

Comment: This doesnt work for me. Occasionally an image flashes as you scroll but generally there is no image shown.

Comment: If im understanding your code correctly it relies on the filenames always being 1.jpg, 2.jpg etc. However this is not the case. Sorry for the lack of clarity, ive updated my question.

Comment: @gbtimmon: you are right, I corrected that. It should fix the flashing. If you have other filenames, create an array with the names and replace `(scrollPos / scrollInterval).toString() ` with `array[scrollPos / scrollInterval]`

Answer (score 0):

```
var defaultFile = 'someDefualtFile.fl'; 
var fileNames = (
    'images/thisIsTheFirstFile.jpg',
    'images/thisIsNotAFile.png',
    'images/testTest.test'
    ...
    ...
    ...
);

var index = Math.floor($(window).scrollTop() / scrollInterval );
var file = fileNames[index] || defaultFile;
$('#img-main').attr('src', file);
```

Comment: This works for my 8 images, but when I add 2 more images then when i scroll to the bottom then no image is shown.

Comment: If im understanding your code correctly it relies on the filenames always being 1.jpg, 2.jpg etc. However this is not the case. Sorry for the lack of clarity, ive updated my question.